# class extending database class works using credentials everytime i instantiate

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm having trouble with two classes, I'm not such an expert with php, pdo, and objects.

this is the issue, I have a class database

```
<?php

/**
* Database class
*/
class database
{
    protected $conection;

    function __construct($conectionData, $user, $password){
        $this->conection = new PDO($conectionData, $user, $password);
        $this->conection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $this->conection;
    }
}

?>
```

and the class which extends

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class micros extends database
{

    public function getAll(){
        $micros = array();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM micros;';
        $sth = $this->conection->prepare($sql);

        if($sth != false) {
            $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Micro');
            $sth->execute();

            while($micro = $sth->fetch()) {
                $micros[] = $micro;
            }
        }

        return $micros;
    }?>
```

and i can just call the extended class by using the database class constructor

```
$db = new database("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=micros_admin","root","");

$micros = new micros("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=micros_admin","root","");
$all = $micros->getAll();
```

like that, I'd like to call just one time the database class, and then be able to call any other class without the need of writing again the params for database class, any help is appreciated.

Comment: With exception mode, the `prepare()` method will **never** return `false` so no need to check for it

Comment: To answer your question, don't create the PDO connection inside your class constructor. Create it externally and pass it in to the constructor instead. This is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: k, im reading about this, but i dont get where the "new pdo()" call should be, should it still be inside database class?

Comment: No, outside, eg `$pdo = new PDO(...); $micros = new micros($pdo);`. If you're feeling up to a challenge, take a look at http://php-di.org/ for dependency injection management

Comment: so i just get one $pdo and in all my other classes i do new class($pdo) right? and with this in mind should other classes still be extensions of database? or standalone clases?

Comment: I'd probably change the `database` class to `Entity` or `Model` or something similar. You can keep it to provide a shared constructor and access to the `protected $connection` object if you like

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey, no problem. It's great that you asked this question. It shows that you're thinking about better design. If you take a look around http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, you may find similar questions and some good answers

Comment: @Phil Side question: Could he also do the old `parent::__construct($conectionData, $user, $password);` from his `micros` class or is DI the way to go?

Comment: @Darren Not sure I understand what you mean. Why would OP want to do that?

Comment: @Phil Scratch that, read the question wrong. I need more coffee D: